# How to apply css filter so that colors behind it come in a particular way

Tags: css

Looking at this codepen what are the styles (maybe css filter) that have to be applied to the .filter class such that .box elements appear to have background: #f7f7f7 and border-color of #fff.  Basically is it possible to filter the .box background to one color and the .box border color to another color.

https://codepen.io/trainiac/pen/qBpXJyj

```
.backdrop {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.box {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e8e7e7;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.filter {
   /* 
    what css filter and styles go here 
    so that .box 
    appears to have background: #f7f7f7
    and border color to be: #fff
   */    
}

<div class="backdrop">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="filter"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
   <div class="filter"/></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
   <div class="filter"/></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
   <div class="filter"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS, so it is impossible to style `.box` based on the condition of `.filter`. The best you can do is style `.box` directly, then style `.filter` to meet child element styling requirements.

Comment: When content is added, do you intend for .box to be fully covered by .filter, or would there be some unfilled area of .box? Obviously, if the .filter div occupies all of the .box, then you will see .filter styles (so set them to whatever you want, .box styles become irrelevant). I'm not sure I understand your problem.